# In ReactGrid Is there a limit to the number of rows that can be displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, spreadsheet

I'm following the example here:

[ReactGrid Getting Started](https://reactgrid.com/docs/4.0/1-getting-started/)

From the example, there is a an array of People objects of length 3 which gets rendered. When I try to add several hundred or several thousand additional People objects only about 27 to 38 (it seems to be random) are ever displayed.

How many rows for a single grid can ReactGrid display?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you were to post your own code. I used Find tool in my browser and still couldn't figure out what "*27 to 38*" numbers were you talking about in the provided Docs?

Comment: Things can't *seem to be random* in programming; you either code it to be randomized or code the design to limits the displayed elements.